# Android studio on mac: remove proxy settings

Tags: java, android, proxy, android-gradle-plugin

I work on macOS High Sierra with Android Studio 3.1 (same problem with 2.3).

I had previously a proxy settings, but actually we stop using proxy.

When i try to update gradle to 4.4 (or other version) android studio apprently continue to use an old proxy settings.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.pom'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.pom'.
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to proxy-********:8080 [proxy-********/172.20.10.5] failed: connect timed out
```

I already disabled the proxy in preferences > system settings > HTTP Proxy.

Someone have an idea?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I finally fixed my problem, if someone needs the solution:

My old proxy settings were stored in the file `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Comment: android 3.1.2 not storing any proxy in gradle.properties ,so where can i remove the saved proxy values

Comment: You have no idea how much I want to thank you right now!!! I had already spent hours on this! It is in moments like this I wish Stackoverflow had something more than just an upvote button!

Answer (score 16):

Gradle daemon retains the reference to proxy even after removing them from the System Preferences. So I had to kill the daemon and start it again to make it work.

```
./gradlew --stop
```

Comment: Did the problem arise again or did `./gradlew --stop` fix it permanently?

Comment: @dtypist, the idea is to make gradle use the updated proxy server information which it wasn't until it was killed.

Comment: This answer is best. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Remove proxy from *all* of the following places.

1. File > Settings > System settings > HTTP Proxy
2. Project gradle.properties
3. ~/.gradle/gradle.properties (As mentioned in the previous answer by @seorefbe)

Answer (score 14):

Go to Android Studio ->Preferences ->search Gradle

You will find path to your Gradle home defined here

**Service directory path :/Users/username/.gradle**

Go to this path from finder and update **gradle.properties** to enable disable proxy(comment proxy set here)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, after removing proxy from following places,

1. File > Settings > System settings > HTTP Proxy Project
2. gradle.properties

my Android Studio still connects to github via proxy. Then I ran the following command to remove proxy for git (I use Windows).

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Now, my Android Studio does not connect to proxy. Hope this helps.